# Where MySql store file.sql in Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, windows, shell, cmd, admin

C:\Users\Paolo\Desktop\cogito>mysql -u root -p "--default-character-set=utf8" cogito_importato < cogito_database.sql.

After execution evrything seems work fine, But if I wont execute this operation with MySQL client what I have to do? May be should be better put before cogito_database.sql in the same directory of cogito_importato. In other word MySQL client from where directory read information about db.sql?

Comment: *In other word MySQL client from where directory read information about db.sql?* `@@secure_file_privilege` directory seems to be the best choice. This unifies the point of all file operations performed from MySQL in the filesystem and minimizes the number of directories which needs special access rights.

Comment: Ok... I look for this directory under my O.S Windows 10 but I didn't find it.... I can perform a select or a "show table" directly on sakila.sql or world.sql from MySql client but I don't do that for a file.sql located for example on Descktop Directory.... Little help please....

Comment: ??? What is current `@@secure_file_privilege` variable value on your server?

Comment: How to see this variable? I mean  '@@secure_file_privilege' and how do you add mini-markers, i tried to do that, but i don't understando how....

Comment: o_O `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;`

Comment: good hint..it works....

Comment: I get this output: 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\' But this directory doesn't exist under Windows 10. I checked the little box "show hidden files and directories" but a Directory or File Uploads ther'isnt. Some explanation?..... How do you add mini_Markdown Formatting? I tried again....

Comment: *But this directory doesn't exist under Windows 10.* Impossible. Server would report an error on startup.

Comment: I executed thi operation and the output was "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\" but directory Uploads doesn't exist on my OS win 10. I checked the box show hidden file and directories, but I am unable to see it. Any explanation?

Comment: Sorry I added on more time my question....